# User Group Change

Tags: groups

I have changed the default group of a user using chgrp command. After that I'm getting the error message" 'Username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported" for basic commands like sudo yum install update.

Any idea. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to see the sudoers file, but it is possible that this user was part of a group, and group had sudoers rights. Now it's no longer part of correct group, so doesn't get sudo permissions.

Example from sudoers file:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Now, if your user `myuser` was part of `admin` group, and now it's changed to `someother` group, it won't match any of the two lines.. it is not `root` and it is not in `admin`.

If you have another root/admin user or someone else has it, need to use it to add you either to correct group or your username explicitly to `sudoers` file.

Please check that first!

Comment: Thank you very much @LuxZg So we should add the user back to admin group to get the sudo access?

Comment: Indeed, if user was in such a group this is most likely the reason.